# How can I code checks with repeating "If Not Cancel then" more elegantly

Tags: ms-access, vba, coding-style

In MS Access VBA, I have different checks in different methods using different parameters. As soon as one of them fails, Cancel is set to True and no further checks should be executed. It looks like that:

```
Cancel = checkMethodOne(param1)

If Not Cancel Then
    Cancel = checkMethodTwo(param2, param3)
End If

If Not Cancel Then
    Cancel = checkMethodThree(param4)
End If
```

... and so on. Is there a way to code this more elegantly without the repeating "If Not Cancel Then" clauses?

Something like "While Not Cancel" seems a problem because of the different methods with individual names and parameters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `And` to evaluate multiple statements, and return false if any return false:

```
Cancel =  checkMethodOne(param1) And checkMethodTwo(param2, param3) And checkMethodThree(param4)
```

If this is convenient for you might depend upon the situation. It's shorter and more code golf-y, but might be more confusing.

Note that this does evaluate all functions, so if they are performance-intensive it might run a bit longer

Alternatively, you can try the following `Select case` to avoid executing all the comparisons:

```
Cancel = True

Select Case True
     Case checkMethodOne(param1)
     Case checkMethodTwo(param2, param3)
     Case checkMethodThree(param4)
     Case Else
        Cancel = False
End Select
```

Comment: My individual check methods include showing a Message Box to the user when a check fails, so this would result in displaying many checkboxes after each other for every failed check. This is not want I want... unfortunately VBA doesn't support [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), otherwise this would work for me.

Comment: Ah, I've provided a second solution for that case

Comment: Wow, this is a tricky solution! I'll use this, it's very compact. I only changed "Select Case True" to "Select Case False", because the checkMethods return False in case of an error.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a simple *If-ElseIf* block:

```
If checkMethodOne(param1) Then
    Cancel = True
ElseIf checkMethodTwo(param2, param3) Then
    Cancel = True
ElseIf checkMethodThree(param4) Then
    Cancel = True
End If
```

Alternative:

```
Cancel = True
If checkMethodOne(param1) Then
ElseIf checkMethodTwo(param2, param3) Then
ElseIf checkMethodThree(param4) Then
Else
    Cancel = False
End If
```

Comment: I like this already better than the code in my question, but I prefer [Erik's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50058668/360480) because it's even more compact without repeating "Cancel = True".

Comment: Yes, the _Select Case_ is neat. The repeated code can be avoided, and then you end up with code similar to Eric's - which I didn't want to just duplicate.